# Cannot locate tasks that match 'spring-boot:run' as project 'spring-boot' not found in root project 'demo'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am new to Java and Spring and am trying to run the demo program from [the Spring official quickstart tutorial](https://spring.io/quickstart)

upon reaching the point where it tells me to enter `gradlew.bat spring-boot:run` into CMD, I get the error **Cannot locate tasks that match 'spring-boot:run' as project 'spring-boot' not found in root project 'demo'.**

I am using Java version 19.0.2 and Spring Boot version 3.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guide is incorrect. The correct task is `bootRun`:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#running-your-application

`./gradlew bootRun`

The `spring-boot:run` the guide specifies is for the Maven Spring Boot plugin: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run